# ¿Usar timestamp?

Tags: laravel

Cuando se crea una nueva migración con laravel, se crea por defecto en todas las tablas un timestamps, y este almacena un valor en la columna created_at y updated_at, estos se llena automáticamente al almacenar un nuevo registro, yo necesito obtener el valor de la fecha de creación y modificación, de un registro, el problema es que la columna updated_at al inicio toma el mismo valor que la de created_up, mi duda es, como genero mi propio timestamp para el update.

Comment: El updated_at es la columna que laravel toma para tener un registro de actualizaciones en los datos, al principio el toma el mismo valor de created_at por que simplemente el crear es una acción de actualización, el está queriendo decir que la ultima actualización que se hizo de los datos fue la creación, espero haber sido claro "!

Comment: Eso lo sé, el problema está en que yo necesito que la fecha de modificación aparezca hasta que yo actualice el registro, por esta razón quiero saber como puedo atrapar la fecha y hora en que se hace dicha actualización, sin utilizar la columna updated_at, sino una propia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,

Lo que se me ocurre es que podes hacer una de estas tres cosas:

1. Al momento de mostrar los datos comparar si `created_at`y `updated_at`son iguales, y en ese caso no mostrar `updated_at` (o hacer una función/método en el modelo que haga esto)
2. Hacer una migración para agregar una columna de tipo booleana `edited` que por default sea `false`y una vez que se edita el modelo además de guardar los cambios se verifica si `edited` es `false`, en cuyo caso se cambia a `true`.
   Luego, al momento de mostrar los datos, si `edited` es `true` mostrar la columna `udated_at`
3. Hacer una migración para agregar una columna de tipo datetime `last_update`que por default sea `null` y una vez que se edita el modelo (como el metodo anterior) darle el valor del tiempo actual, luego utilizar la columna para mostrar el tiempo.

Para los metodos 2 y 3 el cambio de `edited` o `last_update` lo podés realizar de diferentes formas:

1. Realizar el cambio cuando actualizas el modelo, ya sea en el metodo del controlador o donde sea que lo hagas.
2. Observar el evento `updated` o  `updating`del modelo ya sea [fuera](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) o [dentro](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/is-there-any-way-to-listen-for-an-eloquent-event-in-the-model-itself) del modelo.

Espero que esto responda tu pregunta y que me haya explicado bien, cualquier duda me comentas e intentaré aclararme mejor o buscar otra solución.

Comment: Cómo se haría el método 3 que me has dicho?

Comment: Ya logre resolverlo con un IF en la vista, utilizando el método 1 que me has dicho. Gracias